# PHP date() working sporadically

Tags: php, date, strtotime, date-conversion

I am converting two strings from one date format to another but I am getting some unusual responses

The two dates i am converting are:

1: 2002-09-23

2: 2010-03-25

The PHP code is as follows for each of the dates:

1:`date('d F Y', strtotime((string)$report_display->arr_output_base['Date1']['value']));`

2:`date("d F Y", strtotime((string)$report_display->arr_input_base['Date2']['value']));`

The responses I'm getting are as follows:

1:Sometimes 31 December 1986 which is wrong but then other times I'll get 23 September 2002 which is right

2: is always 25 March 2010

Comment: Have you checked your server? It could be possible your host server is causing issues?

Comment: Well since posting this question it has been fine haha. typical!! what would I be checking on my server exactly?

Comment: just check the servers time. I mean, at the end of the day it is just a file server in principle which allows people to view the files through a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you know the format, why take risks sending it to strtotime and not use a proper method that uses the exact format?

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2002-09-23');
echo $date->format('d F Y');
```

That way there is no guesswork involved as to whether a month is a month or it is a day. That will always return the same date no matter what.

Comment: OK so this is working and is a much more sensible approach so you're the winner! have a tick shaped cookie :D